# Devise Password Confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When a user tries to delete their account, I want to display a confirmation screen in which they have to put in their current password. How do I go about checking if their inputted password is their current password?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check by using `#valid_password?`  http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#valid_password%3F-instance_method

So `current_user.valid_password?(pass)`

Comment: I guess I should of looked a little farther into the documentation. Thanks :)