# Michael Hartl's sample_app User Edit current_password edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, change-password

I'm a Rails newbie who just finished Michael Hartl's learing Rails tutorial.  What a great guy!

My goal in life for the last five hours has been to force the user to enter their old password as part of the password update process in the User Edit page.

This is as far as I've gotten;

I've added this field to the (sample_app) edit.html.erb page.

```
  <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
```

I also updated user.rb with 'current_password' as below

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :email, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation,
```

This is the current server side error mesage I'm getting (I've 'googled the error message! a hundred times')

```
"ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in UsersController#update

unknown attribute: current_password
Rails.root: /Users/nicolemcnight/rails_projects/sample_app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:55:in `update'"
```

Clearly there is something wrong in the users_controller, specifically 'def update' which currently looks like this;

```
def update
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

My question is what modifications do I need to make to 'def update' to include the `current_password` attribute!?  And any other updates I need to make?

Basically all I want to do is force the user to confirm their old password before entering (and confirming) a new password on the User Edit page.

Where am I going wrong here?

Any help is appreciated!

here is my github

https://github.com/mwcahn/sample_app

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add :current_password to attr_accessor, not attr_accessible - they are two very different things. As so

```
attr_accessor :current_password
attr_accessible :name, :email, ... etc
```

current_password is now a valid attribute of the User model.

That said, you still need to add code to your model to make it to do the password check before the update. Something like

```
before_update :confirm_passwords

def confirm_passwords
    if current_password != password
        errors.add(:current_password, "Does not match password")
    end
end
```

Note that the above code is for demo purposes only. The actual password value in the database is/should be encrypted. So you can't just do current_password != password. You need to convert your current_password with the same encryption you used on password and compare that value. If you are using Rails' default has_secure_password this should work (but untested) -

```
def confirm_passwords
    errors.add(:current_password, "Does not match password") unless self.authenticate(current_password)
end
```

Comment: ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UsersController#update

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: current_password

Comment: If you get the mass assignment error, add :current_password to attr_accessible as well. Contrary to what @user1559108 wrote, you should NOT be adding a current_password field to your database. You already have the password of the user saved. Writing attr_accessor :current_password creates a current_password attribute that is NOT database backed. There is no reason to create a database column for this at all, it makes no sense.

Comment: Ok I destroyed (rails destroy) the adding of the current_password field.  I added the before_update (haven't seen that before).  Now no error messages, but no error messages at all :(  I can type anything I want into the current_password field.  I just pushed everything to my github github.com/mwcahn.  thanks for your help so far!  i feel the progress!

Comment: @mwcahn: So two things: You wrote before_update :confirm_passwords but then in the method definition name you wrote def current_passwords. Obviously they need to match. It needs to be def confirm_passwords

Comment: @mwcahn also the confirm_passwords method should simply be: def current_passwords (newline) errors.add(:current_password, "Does not match password") unless self.authenticate(current_password) (newline) end

Comment: @mwcahn ie copy the def confirm_passwords exactly from the 2nd version I put above in the actual answer body and try it

Comment: Hi, back to my computer after a long drive.  Thx for response.  I made both edits.  Still nothing, no matter what password I put in the current_password field.  I can even leave all there password fields blank and it also just flashes 'profile updated'.  I'll start with googling before_update and see what I can figure out.

Comment: to me i dont't see where in the def confirm_passwords the old password is being compared

Comment: here's the answer!  I just don't know where exactly to put the code and what it looks like in full   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965826/devise-password-confirmation

Answer (score -1):

One more check: Ensure you did a migration of the database

rails generate migration add_current_password_to_user current_password:string

rake db:migrate

in case you forgot that.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Did both.  Trying to figure out how to post new error message to this discussion now.  Not sure to do it in comments.  Or edit my original question.

Comment: ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UsersController#update

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: current_password

Comment: Well, making it attr_accessible should get rid of it. attr_accessor explicitly disallows a mass assignment. I suspect your first error was because you did not migrate. Can you confirm this?

Comment: don't add a database field.  It makes no sense.